# Lync detect and prompt to install LWA plugin

Tags: plugins, lync

I am able to detect if the plugin is installed but I don't know how to prompt the user to install it or offer to install it for them.  Any ideas?
Name: Microsoft Lync Web App Plug-in
Version: 15.8.20013.20231
LWAPlugin15.8.dll
Type: NPAPI
MIME type: application/x-lwa-nativeplugin15.8

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. You want to know how to link someone to an installer page? Or do you want to actually drive the install from within your page (which could only be done with another NPAPI plugin)?

Comment: When a user goes to a page, I need to check if they have the LWAPlugin installed.  If the LWAPlugin isn't installed, I need to prompt them to install it.  Is that clearer?

Comment: Not really; see the specific question I asked. There's a huge difference between directing someone to a plugin vendor's download page, and trying to actually install native software from within your page.

Comment: Yes I want to install native software from within my page.

Answer (score 0):

I combined information from a few sources into the following solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
numPlugins = navigator.plugins.length;
    var plugins = navigator.plugins;

    var mimeTypeArray = [];
    if (numPlugins > 0)
        document.writeln("Installed plug-ins");
    else
        document.writeln("No plug-ins are installed.");

    for (i = 0; i < numPlugins; i++) {
        plugin = navigator.plugins[i];

        numTypes = plugin.length;
        for (j = 0; j < numTypes; j++)
            {
                mimetype = plugin[j];

              if (mimetype){
                  enabled = "No";
                  enabledPlugin = mimetype.enabledPlugin;
                  if (enabledPlugin && (enabledPlugin.name == plugin.name))
                      enabled = "Yes";

                  mimeTypeArray.push(mimetype.type);
              }
          }
      }
      //alert(mimeTypeArray.toString());
      var lyncSearch = mimeTypeArray.indexOf("application/x-lwa-nativeplugin15.8");
      //alert("lyncSearch = " + lyncSearch);
          if (lyncSearch == -1) {
              $.fileDownload('/evisit/secure/plugins/LWAPlugin-15.8.20013.20231.msi')
                  .done(function () { alert('File download a success!');})
                  .fail(function() { alert('File download failed!'); });
          }
  </script>
```